# insertRowsAtIndexPaths: with scrollToRowAtIndexPath: causes UITableView sections to be incorrectly hidden

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uikit

I've created a UITableview with sections that are clickable.  When you click on them,

1. they "expand" to reveal cells within them
2. the clicked section scrolls to the top of the view.

I calculate all of the indexpaths to insert/delete the necessary cells and then insert them with the following code:

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:pathsToOpen withRowAnimation:insertAnimation];
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:pathsToClose withRowAnimation:deleteAnimation];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[pathsToOpen objectAtIndex:0]  atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

There's only one problem- the sections below the selected section are hidden.  The first screen-shot shows how the tableview should look.  The second screen-shot shows how it actually looks.

[image: Sections Disappear]

If you scroll up (so the hidden sections are offscreen) and then scroll back down, the hidden sections are brought back (once again visible).  My guess as to why this is happening is the following:

The insert/delete animations are happening at the same time as the `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` and it is confusing the TableView.  If I hadn't done `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` sections 3 & 4 would have been offscreen - and so the tableView somehow still thinks they are offscreen.  UITableview hides cells/sections that are offscreen as an optimization.  If I call `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` with a `dispatch_after` with 2 seconds, then sections 3 & 4 are displayed correctly.

So I think I know why this is happening, but I don't know how to fix/override this UITableview optimization.  Actually, if I implement `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation` and then add a breakpoint in this function, the app displays sections 3 & 4 correctly (that's how I got the first screen-shot).  But once continuing from this function, the cells disappear.

The full project can be downloaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/2ks8pw8q6mhb2u2/o2SzAuFmGi/DiveNav-ExpandableSections)

---

Additional implementation details: Sections are legitimate UITableView sections.  I've added a tapGestureRecognizer that triggers a delegate callback to the tableview.  Included below is the entire method that opens the sections.

```
- (void)sectionHeaderView:(SectionHeaderView *)sectionHeaderView sectionOpened:(NSInteger)sectionOpened
{
    // Open
    sectionHeaderView.numRows = DefaultNumRows;
    sectionHeaderView.selected = YES;
    NSMutableArray *pathsToOpen = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < sectionHeaderView.numRows; i++)
    {
        NSIndexPath *pathToOpen = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:sectionOpened];
        [pathsToOpen addObject:pathToOpen];
    }

    // Close
    NSMutableArray *pathsToClose = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    if (openSectionHeader)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < openSectionHeader.numRows; i++)
        {
            NSIndexPath *pathToClose = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:openSectionHeader.section];
            [pathsToClose addObject:pathToClose];
        }
    }

    // Set Correct Animation if section's already open
    UITableViewRowAnimation insertAnimation = UITableViewRowAnimationBottom;
    UITableViewRowAnimation deleteAnimation = UITableViewRowAnimationTop;
    if (!openSectionHeader || sectionOpened < openSectionHeader.section)
    {
        insertAnimation = UITableViewRowAnimationTop;
        deleteAnimation = UITableViewRowAnimationBottom;
    }

    openSectionHeader.numRows = 0;
    openSectionHeader.selected = NO;
    openSectionHeader = sectionHeaderView;


    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:pathsToOpen withRowAnimation:insertAnimation];
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:pathsToClose withRowAnimation:deleteAnimation];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[pathsToOpen objectAtIndex:0]  atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: I think you'ld better use the MVC provided by Apple. All you have to do is to add/remove data into your datasource and do not touch the tableview rows

Comment: Please include a bit more of your project in the question, rather than expecting a download - for example, how do you calculate the index paths to add / remove, and are your "Section X" things section headers or are they just cells? It would make for a better standalone question if it wasn't so dependent on downloading your project.

Comment: I think your guess is right, as well. Can you try reloading the rows at the scroll ended delegate method?

Comment: @jrturton Thanks for the feedback.  I've included more of the implementation details in the question.  I've also made the link to the project a zip that is easier to download.  I actually already tried the tableview reload and it was of no help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I can tell, the problem is occurring when returning a section view that's already been used.  Instead of:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.sectionHeaderViews objectAtIndex:section];
}
```

I get no problem if I create a new view each time:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    SectionHeaderView *sectionHeaderView = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SectionHeaderView_NibName];
    sectionHeaderView.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Section %d", section];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:sectionHeaderView action:@selector(handleTap:)];
    [sectionHeaderView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
    sectionHeaderView.section = section;
    sectionHeaderView.delegate = self;
    return sectionHeaderView;
}
```

It's possible this is occurring because you're using `[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SectionHeaderView_NibName];` to create section headers and hold on to them in an array, which I don't think UITableViewCell was created for, but I'm not certain.  You may want to consider foregoing UITableViewCell for section views and instead use something else (perhaps a UIImageView with a UILabel).  Or you can just not store the Section Views in an array...the way you currently have your code set up, you don't need the array and creating a new view is trivial enough you don't need to worry about it.

Answer (score 5):

@AaronHayman's answer works (**and IMO the accept and bounty should go to him, as it stands - this just didn't fit in a comment!**), but I would go further - you shouldn't be using a cell at all for section header, and you shouldn't be using the dequeue mechanism to essentially load a nib.

Section header view's aren't supposed to be cells, and you may get unforseen effects by using them in place of regular views, particularly if they are deqeueued - the table is keeping a list of these reusable cells when you do that, and recycles them when they go off screen, but your section headers *aren't* reusable, you have one per section.

In your sample project, I changed the superclass of SectionHeaderView to be a plain UIView, and changed your `createSectionHeaderViews` method to load directly from the nibs there:

```
NSMutableArray *sectionHeaderViews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    UINib *headerNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:SectionHeaderView_NibName bundle:nil];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        SectionHeaderView *sectionHeaderView = [[headerNib instantiateWithOwner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        sectionHeaderView.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Section %d", i];

        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:sectionHeaderView action:@selector(handleTap:)];
        [sectionHeaderView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
        sectionHeaderView.section = i;
        sectionHeaderView.delegate = self;

        [sectionHeaderViews addObject:sectionHeaderView];
    }
    self.sectionHeaderViews = sectionHeaderViews;
```

I also commented out the register for reuse line from your viewDidLoad. This prevents the section headers from disappearing.

Comment: Good idea showing him how to instantiate the view from a Nib.  I usually create all my views in code so I didn't even think of that.